# Amazon SES attachment error for ICS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am facing attachment error with Amazon SES service. Normal `pdf` or `jpg` files are attached properly. But when i attach a `.ics` file which is a calender file. I got this error.

```
554 Transaction failed: Illegal filename 'file_name.ics'
```

I am using `aws-ses` gem with `rails 3.2.2`

Is there any limitation from Amazon? And how can we request them to allow this mime type to our account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual issue was that the email has content type `multipart/mixed` and the part which holds the `ics` file has the cotent type `text/plain`, According to [Amazon MIME Types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/MIMETypes.html), `text/plain` must have extensions `txt, diff, text`. But in my case it was having `.ics` extension.

So i have to change the code from this.

```
attachments["file_name.ics"] = @model.to_ical
```

to this.

```
attachments["file_name.ics"] = {:mime_type => 'text/calendar',
                                            :content => @model.to_ical}
```

and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

While [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) does not accept every MIME type indeed, *Content Type* `text/calendar`and *Extension* `ics` are properly supported as per their respective [Appendix: MIME Types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/MIMETypes.html).

Without looking at their source, I suspect this to be a limitation of the [aws-ses](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses) gem eventually (the list of MIME types supported by SES has grown over time) and suggest you give the official [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) (AWS Ruby Gem) a shot instead, which should nowadays provide more consistent and properly maintained development/usage experience for all already supported AWS services.

Good luck!

Comment: Really thanks for this great tip about `AWS SDK`. But in my case the problem was different. I solved it, posting solution in the answer.